# Jquery PHP JSON output associative array

Tags: json, jquery

I have a php code that is outputting an associative array in json. How can I access the objects in the array. I know to access the first item in the json array I'll have to put `data.item0.adlink` but I want to iterate through the `data` object and output everything for each object in the json array. My array and code is below. Thanks.

Array

```
{"item0":{"image":"preview.jpg","file":"video.mp4","adImage":"none","adLink":"http:\/\/sammyukavi.com\/"},"item1":{"image":"preview.jpg","file":"video.mp4","adImage":"none","adLink":"http:\/\/sammyukavi.com\/"},"item2":{"image":"preview.jpg","file":"video.mp4","adImage":"none","adLink":"http:\/\/sammyukavi.com\/"}}
```

Code

```
    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {'first':'1','last':'3'} ,
                        beforeSend: function(x) {
                            if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                                x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                            }
                        },
                        url: 'test.php',
                        success: function(data) {
//I want to get a single item from the data object
                            $.each(data,function(){
//output a property for the single item here
console.log($(this))
                          })
                        }
                    })
                };
```

Comment: Do console.error(data) and paste your data object. Chances are it isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how I can access the second array?

Comment: You cannot use numbers as keys. Instead, use a word, say "item" as the key, and then create an "index" key in each item object holding the number.

Comment: Thanks noted, this comes from a php script outputting the array. I there a way I can count the number of indexes in an object?

Comment: if you can use console.log then you can simply understand

Comment: here is a shot of the log. I can't make out what to do next. http://sammyukavi.com/Capture.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for.

```
function(data) {
                        $.each( data, function( index, value ) {
                            console.log(value)
                        })
                    }
```